# Drools 6 : no-loop and salience

Tags: java, drools

I am using Drools 6 and I have a strange behaviour when I mix no-loop and salience in my drl.

```
rule "creation OfferTranslation 1"
    salience 1
    no-loop
    dialect "mvel"
    when 
        not OfferTranslation( source =="Offer1" )
then
    insert(new OfferTranslation("Offer1","Offer1_31415"));
end

rule "creation OfferTranslation 2"
    salience 2
    no-loop
    dialect "mvel"
    when 
        not OfferTranslation( source =="Offer2" )
then
    insert(new OfferTranslation("Offer2","Offer2_00dsdf")); 
end


rule "creation OfferTranslation 3"
    salience 3
    dialect "mvel"
    when 
        not OfferTranslation( source =="Offer3" )
then
    insert(new OfferTranslation("Offer3","Offer3_00dsf")); 
end


rule "creation OfferTranslation 4"
    salience 4
    dialect "mvel"
    when 
        not OfferTranslation( source =="Offer4" )
then
    insert(new OfferTranslation("Offer4","Offer4_0032")); 
end
```

I expected that the rules would be fired in the following order:
- rule "creation OfferTranslation 4"
- rule "creation OfferTranslation 3"
- rule "creation OfferTranslation 2"
- rule "creation OfferTranslation 1"

However, when I fired them, I get this order :
- rule "creation OfferTranslation 1"
- rule "creation OfferTranslation 2"
- rule "creation OfferTranslation 4"
- rule "creation OfferTranslation 3"

It looks like the no-loop attribute disable the salience, and no-loop rules have priority.
When I try without no-loop, I get the good order.
How can I use no-loop and salience together ,or what is my mistake?

PS : I know that no-loop is useless in my example, I wrote it to have simpler examples than my actual rules.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the described behaviour. It would be a bug, and reporting this on SO would be pointless anyway. Provide a complete example and report to Drools JIRA.

Answer (score 0):

There is no bug. We believed the rule where fired with a wrong order because we used a logger in a drools listener capturing the matchCreated event. A simple log in the rule showed the rule have been fired in the right order.

Seb & Joseph